# Unicorn Coin Mining Stratagies

Tags: discussion, fun, unicoins

I have found that my Unicorn Coin Mining Strategy is not giving me payouts in large enough sums.

My current strategy is to mine the rocks in the order they appear. Then after I have mined 5 rocks to reset the mining widget as it seams that rocks payout fewer coins over time (law of diminishing returns)

Is there a better strategy for mining for unicorn coins? As I would really like to divide everyone else's rep by 10 and set my own rep above the level of the all mighty Jon Skeet.

Praise be to the Unicorn.

Comment: I recommend out sourcing Unicoin mining.

Comment: Indeed, I think I will out source my unicorn mining to jQuery.

Comment: [I thought it might appear on SO](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1938269#1938269)

Comment: Dam having to go to work to make useless dollars, I want to stay home and write a script to mine the more valuable unicorn currency.

Comment: @DroidDev i'm sure that could be arranged :)

Comment: @DaImTo I think it is just a matter of time. It'll appear on SO. We already have a migrated question from SO on this topic.

Answer (score 28):

There are several tricks you can use:

- **Mine the front rocks first.** The front rocks are nearer to you so you get the better part of the schlemiel the painters algorithm.
- **Use the right rhythm.** The clicking frequency is of vital importance. I have got the best results using the beat of Money money money of ABBA, but if you found better rhythms, please let me no.
- **Use the right equipment.** This one was discovered by accident, but expensive equipment gives more unicoins. Try using a mac book and you drown in unicoins.
- **Timing is essential.** Some moments are better for mining than others. (Sorry you have to discover the details yourself).
- **Use a mouse, not a touch screen.** Touch screens give less coins than mouse clicks. Probably because the mouse pointer is sharper than your fingers.
- **Don't forget to sharpen your mouse pointer.** When you have mined 1000 rocks, your mouse pointer starts to get dull. Visit the microsoft site for a download of the MouseSharpner tool.
- **Hit the rock on the right spot.** Each rock has a right spot. If you click that spot, it will break earlier. You will learn to recognize the right spots.

Good luck and happy mining.

Comment: One advantage of a touch screen is that you can mine multiple rocks simultaneously.

Answer (score 4):

I have a handheld electric massage probe that oscillates at a very high frequency. I find that when I apply the probe to my left mouse button I can mine unicorn coins at a very high velocity. I am however struggling to re-position the cursor once each block has been mined, I am working on this problem at the moment.

Comment: You also don't make any friends this way...

Comment: @Werner Actually, I'm sure the mouse loves it.

Answer (score 4):

```
var fkey = StackExchange.options.user.fkey;
var lastGetRock = 0;
function fetchRock() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/unicoin/rock",
    type: "get",
    success: tryToGetRock
  });
};

function tryToGetRock(rock) {
  if (Date.now() - lastGetRock < 10100) {
    var delta = Date.now() - lastGetRock;
    setTimeout(function(){
      tryToGetRock(rock)
    }, delta);
  } else {
    lastGetRock = Date.now();
    getRock(rock.rock);
  }
}

function getRock(rockId) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/unicoin/mine?rock=" + rockId,
    type: "post",
    data: {
      fkey: fkey
    },
    success: function(data){
      console.log("Successfully mined: "+data.value+" coins at ", (new Date()).toGMTString() );
      setTimeout(fetchRock, 10000+ Math.random()*15000);
    }
  });
};

fetchRock()
```

**EDIT**
Added relative URLs, Added fkey thanks to Derek.

Also made time somewhat random as StackOverflow was catching on and started giving me only 1/0 coins per rock. With the randomization I tend to get 3 instead.

Comment: `fkey` can be programmatically acquired with `StackExchange.options.user.fkey`.

Comment: Thanks, added that in as well as some randomization and relative URLS instead. :)

Answer (score 0):

Time for some jQuery magic:

```
function magic(){ 
    $.getJSON('/unicoin/rock',function(data) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            $.post('/unicoin/mine?rock='+data.rock, {fkey: StackExchange.options.user.fkey})
             .done(function( data ) {
                 console.log("Successfully mined: " + data.value + " coins");
             });
         },10000);
    });
    setTimeout(magic,11000);
}
magic();
```